# How to execute SQL Query in seperate class function of Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am new on CodeIgniter. I want to execute all database queries in a separate class function just for the sake of reuse-ability. ***Same like as in JAVA spring framework.***

**Example: i need the List of all users in different controllers. for this purpose wrote the query for getAllUser() in separate Class Function. After that i can call it from different Controllers**

This is the piece of code that i tried to achieve my goal

It will be my service class

```
class UserManagementServices extends CI_Controller {   
    public static function getAllUsers(){
        $this->load->database();
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    }
    public static function getUser($userId){ ... }
    public static function removeUser($userId){ ... }
    public static function getUserHistory($userId){ ... }
}
```

It will be my controller class

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('userHome');
    }
    public function viewAllUser(){
        include 'application/controllers/UserManagementService.php';
        var_dump(UserManagementService::getAllUsers());
    }
}
```

But this piece of code is not working.

**In CodeIgniter It is not allowing me to execute the query in static method.** 
When i tried this

```
class UserManagementServices extends CI_Controller {   
    public static function getAllUsers(){
        return 'Testing Purpose...';
    }
}
```

and it works fine.

Comment: This is what models are for.  Put these into models, not controllers.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: what i can do in this scenario. If my Query contained multiple Joins


`SELECT * FROM USER, USER_LOG, USER_ROLE, COUNTRY, CITY
WHERE USER.USER_ID = USER_LOG.USER_ID
AND USER.USER_ID = USER_ROLE.USER_ID
AND USER.CITY_ID = CITY.CITY_ID
AND CITY.COUNTRY_ID = COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID`

Comment: Make a model function to run that query?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. How we can execute the SQL Query inside CodeIgniter Library

Following is the code of my CodeIgniter Library Class

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class UserManagementService {
    private $ciInstance;
    function __construct(){
        $this->ciInstance =& get_instance();
        $this->ciInstance->load->database(); 
    }
    public function getAllUsers(){
        $query ="SELECT * FROM USERS";
        return $this->ciInstance->db->query($query);       
    }
}
```

This is my CodeIgniter Controller Class

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){ ... }
    public function viewAllUsers(){
        // .... some piece of code here ....
        $this->load->library('usermanagementservice');
        $users = $this->usermanagementservice->getAllUsers();
        // .... some piece of code here ....
    }   
}
```

**I posted it because. Might be It will be helpful for someone else**

Answer (score 4):

First of all, static methods don't have any CI stuff available. So doing something with the DB won't work from there. Secondly, controllers in CI are generally mapped to URIs, so it's better to use them only that way.

If you have some re-usable code, then creating a helper or a library is what you need. You store those in a separate folder and can then load libraries, for example, like this: `$this->load->library('class_name');` and then access them like this: `$this->class_name->method();`

That doesn't apply to your database though. Data access is handled by your model (*duh*). You create them in a very similar way as libraries, and it's explained nicely in the CI docs, which you should read: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html

Comment: I use both ways for load database in Library `$this->load->library('database');` and `$this->load->database();` but its not working.